# Finding the cause of a ClientSocketException in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, network-programming

I am currently working on a flutter mobile app that should connect to different API services. The services are spring boot applications that run inside separate docker containers. Each container is simulatikg a different API service and is mapped to a different port on the host machine.

The app is able to connect to one API, which can be reached on port 3333 on the localhost. The app can connect to the API and recieves the correct answer from it.

After making the request to the first API, I need to connect to a second one to retrieve different data. This API can be reached on port 5555 on the localhost. However, the connection to the service fails with a `_ClientSocketException`:

```
Exception has occurred.
_ClientSocketException (
ClientException with SocketException: Connection reset by peer (
    OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104), 
    address = 10.0.2.2, port = 35868, 
    uri=https://10.0.2.2:5555/testConnection)
```

The ip address used is the android emulator ip to connect to localhost on the main device. I have no idea why the connection is closed and I also don't really know where the error is. I can connect to both services with postman.

My guess is that the emulator closes the connection but I have no idea how to check it.
This is the network controller which makes the requests:

```
class NetworkController {
  static final String _userURL =
      "https://${_getServiceDomain()}:3333/users/api/v1";
  
  static final String _taskURL =
      "https://${_getServiceDomain()}:5555/task";

  static String _getServiceDomain() {
    if (EnviromentCheck.environment == Environment.isAndroid) {
      return "10.0.2.2";
    } else {
      return "localhost";
    }
  }

  static Future<IOClient> _getIOClient() async {
    //_getIOClient().then((value) => _ioClient = value);
    ByteData userCertificate =
        await rootBundle.load('assets/user_certificate.pem');
    ByteData workTimeCertificate =
        await rootBundle.load('assets/workTime_certificate.pem');
    ByteData taskCertificate =
        await rootBundle.load('assets/task_certificate.pem');

    final SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
    securityContext
        .setTrustedCertificatesBytes(userCertificate.buffer.asUint8List());
    securityContext
        .setTrustedCertificatesBytes(workTimeCertificate.buffer.asUint8List());
    securityContext
        .setTrustedCertificatesBytes(taskCertificate.buffer.asUint8List());

    final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient(context: securityContext);
    final IOClient client = IOClient(httpClient);

    return client;
  }

  
  static Future<http.Response> logUserIntoSystem(
      String username, String password) async {
    IOClient ioClient = await _getIOClient();
    
    final response = await ioClient.post(Uri.parse("$_userURL/login"),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Connection": "Close"
        },
        encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"),
        body: {"username": username, "password": password, "scope": ""});

    ioClient.close();
    return response;
  }


  static Future<http.Response> getAllTasksForUser() async {
    IOClient ioClient = await _getIOClient();
    
    final response = await ioClient.post(Uri.parse("https://10.0.2.2:5555/testConnection"),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Connection": "Close"
        },
        encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"),
        body: {"access_token": "****"});

    ioClient.close();

    return response;
  }
}
```

The exception occurs in the `getAllTasksForUser` method, connecting to 5555 closes the socket. The login above however works fine. As both services are nearly identical in their configuration I doubt the server actually closes the connection, but I am not sure.

My question is, how can I find the cause of the error. What is the best way to approach this situation? Or does anyone now possible causes?

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Are you telling that you can connect to 10.0.2.2:3333 but not to 10.0.2.2:5555 ? If so then what is the difference between the two servers?

Comment: `a server that runs in a docker container.` I have no idea what you mean by that. Or why that would be relevant.

Comment: `app is able to connect to one test service`  Dont understand. Your client socket can connect to some server socket you mean?

Comment: @blackapps I have provided more information to the question. It's not really a "server", it's a spring boot application that provides endpoints to retrieve data from a database. This runs in a docker container. I have separate applications in separate containers which all run on different ports. I can connect to the API on 3333, not on 5555 however. As far as I can tell they should all be the same, but with different endpoints. But if the error could lie there i will look more into it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue for the problem. Apparently, the android emulator is running on port 5555 by default. Or at least starting the android emulator before the docker container leads to a connection reset even with postgres.

If the docker container is started before, the android emulator runs on port 5554, however the connection resets still occur even for port 5555. Switching to a different port, e.g. 6666 for that specific service fixed the problem.

Comment: Hard to see why. If you managed to get a connection at all, the client port number shouldn't cause a reset.